# SQL filter duplicates based on column priority

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working with PHP and MySQL.
Can anybody tell me an efficient way of filtering out duplicate result based on priority?

Example:

I have a table:

```
ID  |  Priority 1  |  Priority 2  |  Priority 3  |  E-Mail
--------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  Apple       |  One         |  Low         | abc@abc.com
2   |  Banana      |  Two         |  Medium      | def@abc.com
3   |  Banana      |  Two         |  High        | def@abc.com
4   |  Banana      |  Two         |  High        | def@abc.com
5   |  Peach       |  Three       |  Low         | ghi@abc.com
6   |  Peach       |  Four        |  High        | ghi@abc.com
```

In the above example, I am looking for a way to only get rows 1, 3 (or 4) and 6.
That is, as the email for row 2,3,4, and 5,6 is the same, they are duplicate records. I want to select records based on priority.
If Priority 1 of duplicate records is the same, I move to Priority 2. If that is also the same, I then move onto Priority 3. If that is the same, then it doesn't matter which I select.
However, if there is a difference, I select the higher priority record.
In the above example, the priorities are

```
Peach -> Banana -> Apple
Four -> Three -> Two -> One
High -> Medium -> Low
```

I would then be inserting the result into a different database.

So far, I have a query to get the non duplicates. I was thinking of having a second query that deals with the duplicates.
The first query deals with approximately 20,000 records. The second query would be dealing with about 5,000 records.

However, I am not sure of an efficient method of accomplishing that.

I would highly appreciate any help.

Thank you.

EDIT: typo: wanted rows 1, 3/4, and 6 (not 1,2, and 6)

Comment: why record 2, that has a medium priority, and not 3 or 4?

Comment: normalisation anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should give you the result that you need:

```
SELECT
  MIN(ID),
  EMail,
  MIN(Priority1),
  MIN(Priority2),
  MIN(Priority3)
FROM
  yourtable
WHERE
  (EMail, Priority1, Priority2, FIELD(Priority3, 'High', 'Medium', 'Low')) IN (
    SELECT
      EMail,
      MIN(Priority1),
      MIN(Priority2),
      MIN(FIELD(Priority3, 'High', 'Medium', 'Low')) MinP3
    FROM
      yourtable
    WHERE
      (EMail, Priority1, FIELD(Priority2, 'Four', 'Three', 'Two', 'One')) IN (
        SELECT
          EMail,
          MIN(Priority1),
          MIN(FIELD(Priority2, 'Four', 'Three', 'Two', 'One')) MinP2
        FROM
          yourtable
        WHERE
          (EMail, FIELD(Priority1, 'Peach', 'Banana', 'Apple')) IN
          (SELECT
             EMail, MIN(FIELD(Priority1, 'Peach', 'Banana', 'Apple')) MinP1
           FROM
             yourtable
           GROUP BY
            EMail)
        GROUP BY
          EMail)
    GROUP BY
      EMail)
GROUP BY
  EMail
```

(I'm returning row 3 instead of 2, but if I understand your question correctly it shoud be correct). Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18d78d/1). I suspect it won't be really fast. I'm still wondering if there's a way to make it faster.

EDIT

You could try the following query. It uses a different logic, but it also uses a Priorities table with some idexed columns, they should be much faster than FIELD function, however there are many joins that could slow the query a little.

```
CREATE TABLE Priorities (
  Num INT,
  Des VARCHAR(10),
  Priority INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (Num, Des)
);

INSERT INTO Priorities VALUES
(1, 'Peach',  1),
(1, 'Banana', 2),
(1, 'Apple',  3),
(2, 'Four',   1),
(2, 'Three',  2),
(2, 'Two',    3),
(2, 'One',    4),
(3, 'High',   1),
(3, 'Medium', 2),
(3, 'Low',    3);

SELECT MIN(ID), yourtable.Email, MIN(Priority1) Priority1, MIN(Priority2) Priority2, MIN(Priority3) Priority3
FROM
  yourtable
  INNER JOIN Priorities p1 ON yourtable.Priority1=p1.Des AND p1.Num=1
  INNER JOIN Priorities p2 ON yourtable.Priority2=p2.Des AND p2.Num=2
  INNER JOIN Priorities p3 ON yourtable.Priority3=p3.Des AND p3.Num=3
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT s1.EMail, MIN(MinP1) M1, MIN(MinP2) M2, MIN(MinP3) M3
    FROM (
      SELECT   EMail, MIN(p1.Priority) MinP1
      FROM     yourtable INNER JOIN Priorities p1
               ON yourtable.Priority1 = p1.Des AND p1.Num = 1
      GROUP BY EMail) s1
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT   EMail, p1.Priority Pr1, MIN(p2.Priority) MinP2
      FROM     yourtable INNER JOIN Priorities p1
               ON yourtable.Priority1 = p1.Des AND p1.Num = 1
               INNER JOIN Priorities p2
               ON yourtable.Priority2 = p2.Des AND p2.Num = 2
      GROUP BY EMail, p1.Priority) s2
    ON s1.EMail=s2.EMail AND s1.MinP1=s2.Pr1
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT   EMail, p1.Priority Pr1, p2.Priority Pr2, MIN(p3.Priority) MinP3
      FROM     yourtable INNER JOIN Priorities p1
               ON yourtable.Priority1 = p1.Des AND p1.Num = 1
               INNER JOIN Priorities p2
               ON yourtable.Priority2 = p2.Des AND p2.Num = 2
               INNER JOIN Priorities p3
               ON yourtable.Priority3 = p3.Des AND p3.Num = 3
      GROUP BY EMail, p1.Priority, p2.Priority) s3
    ON s1.Email=s3.Email AND s1.MinP1=s3.Pr1 AND s2.MinP2=s3.Pr2
  GROUP BY
    s1.EMail) s
  ON yourtable.EMail=s.Email
     AND p1.Priority=s.M1
     AND p2.Priority=s.M2
     AND p3.Priority=s.M3
GROUP BY
  yourtable.EMail
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9615/1). If it's still too slow, we could try to use my first query with a support table like the second one. Or we should divide the query in two parts.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for such a fast response and your time. I really appreciate it. And yes, I wanted row 3 (not 2) - thanks for catching that! This does solve the problem and this is still faster than my current solution (putting the result into an array and then filtering it). However, if you are able to find a faster solution, I would much appreciate it. Again, thank you!

Comment: Hi again, I tried running this query on the actual database of over 20,000 records, and it times out. With about 100 records, it takes over 5 seconds. Although, I appreciate your help, this solution would not work on the database. Do you have any other ideas? Maybe I can divide the queries - as in first I get the non duplicates, then I get the duplicate records and filter just those based on priorities? Thank you!

Comment: @CheekuJee the query is fine i think, there are others solutions but they are very similar. I think that the problem is the FIELD() function that's slow. You should use some additional tables with an index, just give me some time and i'll update my answer